# How to logical OR multiple variables in Powershell

Tags: powershell, logical-or

I thought this was simple. And I'm sure it is. But, I can't seem to crack it.

I have 3 functions that return a `true` or `false` value.

In a later `if` evaluation I am trying to logical `or` the 3 results together.

Something like this:

```
if (Fnc1 -or Fnc2 -or Fnc3) { write-host "Yes" }
```

Not only is Powershell highlighting the syntax differently for the first Fnc1 from the others, it's only returning true or false based on the value of Fnc1 from what I can tell.

I know this works:

```
if ((Fnc1 -eq $true) -or (Fnc2 -eq $true) -or (Fnc3 -eq $true)) { write-host "Yes" }
```

But, that seems like overkill and un-necessary.

What am I missing?

Comment: For syntax highlighting I do agree. If you use `$(fnc2)` syntax highlighting is better. Nevertheless this is working with your first syntax.

Comment: @Hazrelle hi. I am not getting the same result. If Fnc1 is true the whole thing evaluates true. If Fnc1 is false the whole thing evaluates false.

Comment: Are you trying to understand why you must enclose your functions in `(..)` for the expression to be evaluated properly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell attempts to parse the `-or` token as a function parameter when you place it after a function name like that. Surround each function call in `()`:

```
if ((Fnc1) -or (Fnc2) -or (Fnc3)) { write-host "Yes" }
```

Answer (score 1):

another way to get that is to use the `-contains` collection operator. lookee ...

```
function Get-True {$True}
function Get-False {$False}


@((Get-True), (Get-False), (Get-True)) -contains $True
```

output = `True`

if all those were `Get-False`, the result would be `False`.

---

note that this method requires that *all the function calls* be run before the `-contains` operator can test anything. that means the `-or` solution would be more efficient since that would run each function call in sequence and stop when the `-or` was satisfied.

the `-or` solution can be *much* more efficient if the function calls take any significant amount of time or resources.

thanks to @SagePourpre for pointing that out. [*grin*]

Comment: OP specifically mentionned a **logical OR**. Your solution doesn't work under that pretense since a logical OR would stop processing the statements after the first instance of `$true`. Your solution do process all the statements regardless of if a `$true` result was obtained already. This will have a performance cost and potentially unintended side-effects if you did want to use it as a **logical OR** alternative.

Comment: @SagePourpre - ah! that is a good point. yes, my solution would seem to require processing each function call before the `-contains` would be run. ///// should i add that to the Answer or does your comment do the job?

Comment: Since you ask, I like to integrate relevant comments in my own answers. That way my answer become the full stand-alone picture instead of a "Compile your own answer" situation where you have an answer in an unoptimized state and need to read through the comments to get all the informations you need. I usually comment back to let the commenter I edited my answer in the form of a thanks of some sort. tl;dr : I want to craft the perfect answer so if you point out something that can help me achieve that, I will for sure edit my answer every time.

Comment: @SagePourpre - thank you for the feedback. [*grin*]